# Newtonian theory of small perturbations: Continuity equation

Tags: cosmological-inflation, density

Starting with the continuity equation

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla_r(\rho \vec{u}) = 0$$

making those substitutions.
$$\nabla_r = \frac{\nabla_x}{a}$$
$$\rho(\vec{x},t) = \bar \rho(t)[1 + \delta(\vec{x},t)]$$

And then compute the time derivative I get:
$$\frac{\partial \bar \rho}{\partial t} \frac{[1 + \delta]}{\rho} + \dot \delta + \frac{1}{a} \nabla_x [1 + \delta]\vec{u} = 0$$

However, based on this [document](https://people.astro.umass.edu/%7Ehjmo/astro850/lecture3.pdf) the term $\frac{\partial \bar \rho}{\partial t}$ vanishes.

Is it because for small perturbations the mean density is constant? If so, why exactly?

Thank you

Comment: It's neglected because the transformation is is a linear approximation and the first term is non-linear. See slide 10 of the document you linked.